# creating elements through loop inside render function in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
this.state.obj= [{"listing_id":"1","listing_name":"A"},{"listing_id":"2","listing_name":"iima "},{"listing_id":"3","listing_name":"dsffgdf"}];
```

inside render function =>

```
{this.state.obj.map((name,index) => 
  <tr key={index}>
    <td key={index} onClick={this.openOptions.bind(this,name.listing_id)}>{name.listing_id}</td>
    <td key={name.listing_name}>{name.listing_name}</td>
    if(name.listing_id == openOptionsvar){
      <td key={index+1} >Edit</td>
    }
  </tr>
)}
```

i want display last td element if openOptionsvar value equals to listing_id of that row??

Answer (score 1):

`listing_id` is a React.PropTypes.string. Check which propType is openOptionsvar (probably a React.PropTypes.number).
I am afraid they are different properties so you have to convert any of them to the correspondent propType and in your condition use the strict equality comparison, doing for example (if openOptionsvar is number):

```
 if(Number(name.listing_id) === openOptionsvar){
   <td key={index+1} >Edit</td>
 }
```

Comment: I liked, Number(name.listing_id) === openOptionsvar instead , name.listing_id == openOptionsvar.

Answer (score 0):

You can write if condition within map as follows

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
     this.state = {
          obj: [{"listing_id":"1","listing_name":"A"},{"listing_id":"2","listing_name":"iima "},{"listing_id":"3","listing_name":"dsffgdf"}]
     }
  }
  render() {
    var openOptionsvar = 2;
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.obj.map((name,index) => {
      if(name.listing_id == openOptionsvar) {
        return <li>{name.listing_name}</li>
      }}
      )}
     </div> 
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While using any loop in React to render elements, you must use `key`   attribute. And try to use `ternary operator` instead of `for loop`.  The ternary operator is a substitute for an if statement in which both the if and else clauses assign different values to the same field, like so:

```
render() {
        var openOptionsvar = 2;
        return (
          <div>
          {this.state.obj.length>0 && this.state.obj.map((name,index) => {
            return name.listing_id == openOptionsvar? <li key={index}>{name.listing_name}</li>:null
          }
          )}
         </div> 
        )
      }
    }
```

**Edit**: 
use `Number(name.listing_id) === openOptionsvar` in place of `name.listing_id == openOptionsvar`